# Multi-threaded database inserts with incrementing local id

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, concurrency

Given a batch of 100 books, and 100 threads, with 1 book per thread and 1 transaction per book (that could potentially rollback):

How can you safely insert those books into a MySQL table with a guarantee that each book is given an auto incrementing "local id" (i.e, "1001, 1002, ..." without gaps (remember they can potentially rollback).

Example Schema for `books`

```
id | account_id | book_title | book_author | local_id
6     12          Asdf         Jkl;           1000
82    12          John         Jane           1001
```

Comment: You can't.... an autoincrement doesn't guarantee consecutive id values, just unique id values.... you should never make your application dependent on consecutive autoincrement id values

Comment: Can't is a strong word. I was considering using a before insert trigger. Should never is also a pretty strong absolute. Why is it so bad that I give my users a simple easily recallable number for their books. My checkbook has auto incrementing id's for each check, too.

Comment: "Can't" and "should never" are quite fitting, here.  Also, you seem to be be conflating "**auto**-incrementing" (database terminology) with "monotonic."  If an easy to remember number is your goal, okay, but why is "without gaps" important?  How do you envision a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger helping?  If there's a rollback, what about the transactions waiting for the lock that resume immediately after that?  If you "void" a check, you don't renumber all of the remaining checks in the book, downward.

Comment: Strong words, but correct words.... this is a case where you want auto increment to do something that it was never designed, or intended to do

Comment: And you seem a little to tied to my usage of 'auto incrementing'. I did not mean to refer to the AUTO_INCREMENT capabilities of a relational database. Just more the concept of incrementing an integer by 1 for each record (taking app logic suggestions / distributed locking service / number services / whatever you can come up with)